# How to include formBuilder options from another .ts file

Tags: typescript

The following is how my `ComplaintCreateComponent.ts` file looks like.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

...

export class ComplaintCreateComponent implements OnInit {

  public ComplaintForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    ComplaintID: ['', [Validators.required]],
    FileNo: ['', [Validators.required]],
    ComplaintName: ['', Validators.required],
  })
  
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.ComplaintForm);
  }

}
```

I would like put the following options in another .ts file and include that file in the `this.formBuilder.group` options.

```
{
       ComplaintID: ['', [Validators.required]],
       FileNo: ['', [Validators.required]],
       ComplaintName: ['', Validators.required],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just export a variable and import it wherever you want:

**my-form.ts**

```
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export const myForm = {
  ComplaintID: ['', [Validators.required]],
  FileNo: ['', [Validators.required]],
  ComplaintName: ['', Validators.required],
}
```

**ComplaintCreateComponent.ts**

```
import { FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import { myForm } from './my-form';

export class ComplaintCreateComponent {

  public ComplaintForm = this.formBuilder.group(myForm)
  
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
}
```